# C# Entity Framework - Multiple relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationships

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I thought I would ask...

I have two database tables. One is a list of users pulled from Active Directory. The second table is a list of scheduled forwards. The relationship I would like to create would be...

```
public class AdObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryDisplay { get; set; }
    public string CanonicalName { get; set; }
    public string OU { get; set; }
    public string CoreGroup { get; set; }
    public string ForwardedTo { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool? IsForwarded { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverAndRedirect { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableForwardAtLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DisableAtLogonAfter { get; set; }
    public string Notify { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastApiLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastCheck { get; set; }

    // This isn't required. But if possible I would like this to be
    // a relationship to another AdObject whos "PrimaryEmail" matches
    // the "ForwardedTo" column of this AdObject. There will not always
    // be a match though, so not too important just wondering if its possible.
    public AdObject ForwardedToObject { get; set; }

    // This would be a list of forwards where the "ForwardFrom"
    // column matches the "PrimaryEmail" of this AdObject. 
    public ICollection<Forward> ScheduledForwards { get; set; }
        = new List<Forward>();


   // FYI... Technically ID,SamAccountName,PrimaryEmail,DistinguishedName, 
   // and CanonicalName are all unique. They could all be keys. 

}

public class Forward
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ForwardFrom { get; set; }
    public string ForwardTo { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverAndRedirect { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopTime { get; set; }
    public string Recurrence { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableForwardAtLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DisableAtLogonAfter { get; set; }
    public string Notify { get; set; }

    public string StartJobId { get; set; }
    public string StopJobId { get; set; }
    public string StartJobStatus { get; set; }
    public string StopJobStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartJobCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopJobCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartJobCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopJobCreated { get; set; }
    public string StartReason { get; set; }
    public string StopReason { get; set; }

    // This would be the AdObject whos "PrimaryEmail" matches the
    // "ForwardTo" column. 
    public AdObject ForwardToObject { get; set; }

    // This would be the AdObject whos "PrimaryEmail" matches the
    // "ForwardFrom" column. 
    public AdObject ForwardFromObject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Simple answer is yes. Syntax-wise there is nothing stopping you from designing your model this way. The real crux comes down to how you implement the use of this model, for example ask yourself how will you construct this model?

Comment: You might want to look at hierarchy design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it figured out. I was having a hell of a time understanding the logic behind relationships. I had a few misconceptions that I ironed out and after going through every YouTube video, PluralSight Course and Udemy course I could find it finally started to click. I usually don't have this much trouble teaching myself these things, but the misconceptions I had were pointing me in the wrong direction. In the end I only had to specify the keys and two relationships (conventions did the rest).

```
public class AdObject
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryDisplay { get; set; }
    public string CanonicalName { get; set; }
    public string OU { get; set; }
    public string CoreGroup { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool? IsForwarded { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverAndRedirect { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableForwardAtLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DisableAtLogonAfter { get; set; }
    public string Notify { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastApiLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastCheck { get; set; }

    public AdObject ForwardedToObject { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Forward> ForwardRecipientSchedule  { get; set; }
        = new List<Forward>();

    public ICollection<Forward> ForwardSchedule { get; set; }
        = new List<Forward>();
}

public class Forward
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AdObject ForwardFromObject { get; set; }
    public AdObject ForwardToObject { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverAndRedirect { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopTime { get; set; }
    public string Recurrence { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableForwardAtLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DisableAtLogonAfter { get; set; }
    public string Notify { get; set; }
    public string StartJobId { get; set; }
    public string StopJobId { get; set; }
    public string StartJobStatus { get; set; }
    public string StopJobStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartJobCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopJobCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartJobCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StopJobCreated { get; set; }
    public string StartReason { get; set; }
    public string StopReason { get; set; }


}

public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContext() : base("name=EnityContext"){

    }


    public DbSet<AdObject> AdObjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Forward> Forwards { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContext)

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<AdObject>()
            .HasMany(f => f.ForwardSchedule)
            .WithRequired(f => f.ForwardFromObject)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<AdObject>()
            .HasMany(f => f.ForwardRecipientSchedule)
            .WithRequired(f => f.ForwardToObject)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```